# Why ExpandableListView group item scroll to bottom by default?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have 20 group items in expandablelistview displaying in one tab, and at a time only 5 item can be visible on the screen.

I am using setSelectedGroup(9) to set the 10 group to visible when expandablelistview loads. In this case it working as i want, items visible are from 10 to 15 on the screen.

Problem occurs when I try to change the data set list to 10 item only and try to display the first five item using setSelectedGroup(0), in this case when the expandablelistview loads, only bottom five items are visible on screen.

I want to see the top five items to be visible when I change the data set list.

Question is why expandablelistview group items moves to bottom of list? why can't it display from the top.